# Updating attributes from retrieved objects that has required attr_acessors - Rails Tutorial - Michael Hartl's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

On [Chapter 7](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top) from Michael Hartl's tutorial there is a User model <[code here](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/master/app/models/user.rb)> that has a password attribute defined as a attr_accessor and also as attr_accessible with a presence validator.

The problem is: if I retrieve an existent User and try to update its email, ruby throws an exception claiming for its password, and I'm forced to re-set the password every time I want to update any other attribute. Example:

```
User.first.update_attributes!(:email => "example@mail.com")
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

I added ":on => :create" next to the password's presence validator and it seemed to solve the problem. Is this the right solution regarding a login system?

Anyone who has completed the Michael Harlt's tutorial knows if that was an error or it was his real intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the validator to the password hash field so that it is the actual password stored in the database which is checked. If you make the `password=` function set the value of a hash column, then this method will work independently of the actual password virtual variable.

Comment: This could work, but I also want to ensure that the user fill the password field on the creation step, that's why I added the presence validator for the password (the virtual one).

Comment: If you make the validator for the password_hash field, then it will work because password= would update that column.